# Implement unique occurrence against each other

Tags: game-development

I am trying to develop a card game, in which I have a situation like I need to present cards against each other in such a way so that they have never played with each other. So in general, I will have two different stack of cards, and they will be presented with each other. So it could be like

```
 A  B  C  D 
 H  U  O  P
```

Any one of the card will be swiped away from infront of any letter, say user remove H from infront of A, the U will be presented to A, then U swiped away O will be presented.

In above scenario H, U, and O have played with A, so in future they should never play with A.

How to implement this.

Any light, anything that can help me, would be highly appreciated.

**For more clarification, see image below**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "in the future", are we talking "for the rest of this game" (meaning they H/U/O could play with A in a future game, just not for the remainder of this one), or "in any game" like the changes that happen with Risk/Pandemic Legacy, where there are permanent changes made to cards in any given copy of the game?

Comment: You could place player markers on the cards for each interaction.

Comment: @DavidCEllis "in the future" means in next game play, in this game there will be a single card remains, which will become winner. Player can start another game with having same packs of cards, but we need to make sure the cards which had already played with each other doesn't come infront of each other, we are saving the mapping of play between cards, which card played with which one. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few options for this, depending on the permanency of the effect:

**Marker cards**
Track the opposing cards that your card has faced on an object (e.g. Another card with the same title but instead of game text or an image it just has a list of the other cards and checkboxes, or just a section of each card that you mark).

**Tracking sheet**
If you use a separate object for tracking, like a score sheet or even just a piece of paper, it would be easy to track the cards you have played and the cards they have played against.

There are still two major problems here:

1. If the effect is permanent, you're eventually going to be unable to play a given card against any other card, placing a fixed lifespan on a copy of the game.
2. You're attempting to track a many-to-many relationship between cards, so depending on the size of your set this could be an extremely difficult task without some sort of spreadsheet or app or database to help.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCEllis. Yes I am aware of condition 1, and too we are using database to save the occurrences. The main problem I am facing is the logic to filter out the one which played. Anyway thanks.